# Access form label from another class/namespace

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class

I know this has been asked thousands of time but still after a lot of research I can't find a solution and I am really sorry about this post.

I want to access my Label from a class in another namespace.
This is a sample of code to understand better what I am trying to do:

```
public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }



//class in another namespace
class Servers
    {
        public void _SetlabelText()
        {
           Main.label1.Text = "New Text";
        }
    }
```

How am I supposed to do it the proper way?

Comment: In plain terms, you can't. You can create a static instance of the form and access it from the parent class that way: `class Parent{ public static Form myForm { get; set; }` then to access it from another class: `MyNameSpace.Parent.myForm.label1.Text = "some text";` or you can do as Jon does in the answer bellow housing the form in the needed class.

Comment: _SetlabelText() is in the Servers class BUT it is called in the Main form. I just wanted to move the methods in another class so i clean up the mess a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to store a reference to the form in the constructor like this:

```
public class Servers
{
    private Form _frmMain;
    public Servers(Form frmMain)
    {
        _frmMain = frmMain;
    }
    public void SetlabelText()
    {
        _frmMain.label1.Text = "New Text";
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var servers = new Servers(this);
        servers.SetlabelText();
    }
}
```

However, it's typically advised to return back to the Form class and set it there, like this:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = Servers.GetTextForLabel();
    }
}
public class Servers
{
    public static string GetTextForLabel()
    {
       return "New Text"; //(I assume this will be much more complex)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why i can't seem to understand your first example. And why it doesn't work for me? I am really confused

Comment: @Maria Added implementation above

Comment: Yes but that way public void SetlabelText()
    {
        _frmMain.label1.Text = "New Text";
    }
will throw an error. _frmMain.label1.Text does not exists in the class. You can not build it this way.

Comment: @Maria Sounds like you're missing something.