# the labels in my classes are shown as errors and do not work

Tags: c#

in this dice game im making my Form 1 Is now empty as i needed more then 1 class to help me and when i came back today the errors on the labels (label1.text) have error messages and wont work i have done this code in Windows Format Application with a GUI that has labels buttons and a text box eveything is fine except the labels wont work it say its "dosnt exist in current context" what do i do

```
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(6) + 1);
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
        randomNumber = random.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(6) + 1);
        label2.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
        randomNumber = random.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(6) + 1);
        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
        randomNumber = random.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(6) + 1);
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
        randomNumber = random.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(6) + 1);
        label5.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide complete error message? That excerpt you've shown is not very informative.

Comment: So you made a new class and you are trying to reference the labels from the form in it?

Comment: yes thats it i have tried almost anything from using statements to object referanceing but it just not having it. the using stament was the closest but nce i debug it flairs up 20 error messages

Comment: The Error Code is CS0103 for all of them

Comment: You need a reference to your form in the class that you are trying to use the labels in. And the labels cannot be modified `private`. There are hundreds of questions about this, also maybe this will help: https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/forms-are-just-classes/

Comment: Right okay im quite new to all of this so how would one referance i know is sounds stupid but im learning at uni and the lecturers are just reading from the powerpoint and dont really help during workshops

Comment: Here is another example. Search title of this question, you will get many results, it would not be appropriate for me to recreate this wheel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806849/access-form-label-from-another-class-namespace

Comment: Okay thats fine thanks